# emacs major-mode define font-lock for line preceding regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax, lisp

I'm working on making a custom emacs major-mode, but I'm completely unfamiliar with lisp - so I'm struggling.  I'm trying to add a font lock such that a line of repeating '`=`' or '`-`' is highlighted, along with the line above it (so that I can use these as headings), i.e.

```
This is a Colored Heading
=========================

this is a differently-colored sub-heading
-----------------------------------------
```

I've tried to set this up with:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(.*\n=\{3,\}\\)"
                             1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))
```

but it isn't working.  I thought this meant:

'`.*`' any characters
'`\n`' followed by a newline
'`=\{3,\}`' followed by 3 or more '=' characters

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\{"` and `"\}"` are treated as an escape sequence, which they're not.
You need to use `"\\{"` and `"\\}"` instead:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(.*\n=\\{3,\\}\\)"
                             1 font-lock-warning-face prepend)))
```